# How to change keyboard color from UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using a UIAlertView with LoginAndPasswordInput `[message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];` The alertview color is the standard blue color, but the keyboard that pops up is black? How can I change this color from the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer :** [**keyboardAppearance**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html)

Black Keyboard for `UIAlertView` is a standard rule of Human Interface given by Apple as they mentioned `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` with Black Color.

Why do you think it's not a good appearance ? 
However you can change the Color of your Keyboard to **Blue** with this :

```
mytextfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
```

Comment: @nonuma: If it's the case then why apple used `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` with *Black Color* ?

Answer (score 2):

See the keyboard color has nothing to do with the `UIAlertView`. To change the color of the keyboard color you have 2 options.

**For the Blue appearence.**

```
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
```

OR

**For the black appearance.**

```
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```